# cumulative product for specific groups of observations in pandas

Tags: pandas, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset of the following type

```
           Date    ID  window        var
0    1998-01-28     X      -5  8.500e-03
1    1998-01-28     Y      -5  1.518e-02
2    1998-01-29     X      -4  8.005e-03
3    1998-01-29     Y      -4  7.905e-03
4    1998-01-30     X      -3 -5.497e-03
         ...   ...     ...        ...
3339 2016-12-19     Y       3 -4.365e-04
3340 2016-12-20     X       4  3.628e-03
3341 2016-12-20     Y       4  6.608e-03
3342 2016-12-21     X       5 -2.467e-03
3343 2016-12-21     Y       5 -2.651e-03
```

My aim is to calculate the cumulative product of the variable `var` according to the variable `window`. The idea is that for every date, I have identified a window of 5 days around that date /the variable `window` goes from -5 to 5). Now, I want to calculate the cumulative product in the window that belongs to a specific date. For example, the first date (1998-01-28) has a value of `windows` of -5, and thus represent the starting point for the calculation of the cumprod. I want to have a new variable called `cumprod` which is exactly `var` on the date in which `window` is -5, then it is the cumprod between the value of `var`at -5 and -4, and so on until `window` is equal to 5. This defines the value of `cumprod` for the first group of dates, where every group is defined by consecutive dates in a way that `var` starts at -5 and ends at 5. I shall then repeat this for any group of date. I will therefore obtain something like

```
           Date    ID  window        var   cumprod
0    1998-01-28     X      -5  8.500e-03 8.500e-03 
1    1998-01-28     Y      -5  1.518e-02 1.518e-02
2    1998-01-29     X      -4  8.005e-03 6.80425e-05
3    1998-01-29     Y      -4  7.905e-03 0.00011999790000000002
4    1998-01-30     X      -3 -5.497e-03
         ...   ...     ...        ...
3339 2016-12-19     Y       3 -4.365e-04
3340 2016-12-20     X       4  3.628e-03
3341 2016-12-20     Y       4  6.608e-03
3342 2016-12-21     X       5 -2.467e-03
3343 2016-12-21     Y       5 -2.651e-03
```

where I gave an example in of `cumprod` for the first 2 dates.

How could I achieve this? I was thinking to find a way to attach an identifier to every group of dates and then run some sort of `cumprod()` method using `.groupby(group_identifier)`. I can't think of how to do it though. Would it be possible to simplify it by using a `rolling` function on window? Any other kind of approach is very welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.date_range("1998-01-28", freq="d", periods=22),
                   "window": np.concatenate([np.arange(-5,6,1),np.arange(-5,6,1)]),
                   "var": np.random.randint(1,10,22)
                   })
```

My `df` is similar to yours:

```
       Date  window  var
0  1998-01-28      -5    3
1  1998-01-29      -4    3
2  1998-01-30      -3    7
3  1998-01-31      -2    2
4  1998-02-01      -1    4
5  1998-02-02       0    7
6  1998-02-03       1    2
7  1998-02-04       2    1
8  1998-02-05       3    2
9  1998-02-06       4    1
10 1998-02-07       5    1
11 1998-02-08      -5    4
12 1998-02-09      -4    5
```

Then I create a grouping variable and transform var using`cumprod`:

```
df =  df.sort_values("Date") # My df is already sorted by Date given the way 
# I created it, but I add this to make sure yours is sorted by date
df["group"] = (df["window"] == -5).cumsum()
df = pd.concat([df, df.groupby("group")["var"].transform("cumprod")], axis=1)
```

And the result is :

```
        Date  window  var  group     var
0  1998-01-28      -5    3      1       3
1  1998-01-29      -4    3      1       9
2  1998-01-30      -3    7      1      63
3  1998-01-31      -2    2      1     126
4  1998-02-01      -1    4      1     504
5  1998-02-02       0    7      1    3528
6  1998-02-03       1    2      1    7056
7  1998-02-04       2    1      1    7056
8  1998-02-05       3    2      1   14112
9  1998-02-06       4    1      1   14112
10 1998-02-07       5    1      1   14112
11 1998-02-08      -5    4      2       4
12 1998-02-09      -4    5      2      20
13 1998-02-10      -3    1      2      20
```

Comment: I think the part ``` (df["window"] == -5).cumsum()``` was really a good idea, I did not think about that! Thank you!

Comment: do you know I can implement the command keeping track of different values in my ID variable?

Comment: I did not see this, yes you can sort values by ["ID", "Date"]  and apply the same method, as you sorted by ID first, two similar dates in different ID will be in different groups.

Comment: actually what I would need is that despite referring to different ID, the same dates should be associated with the same group. Instead, if I sort by ['ID','Date'] the same dates will belong to different groups. However, I was able to overcome this issue